# Ionic 5 app stuck on white screen after splash screen

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

Our app on the Play Store is getting stuck on a white screen after loading the splash screen. This issue seems to be occurring on devices running Android 10. The app runs fine on iOS and Android 7 and 8. It also works when running locally, and no error message appears when debugging in Chrome.

We have tried adding the setTimeout delay for the splash screen, removing/adding the Android platform, and changing the target SDK version. The last update we made to the app was adding a new preference tag to fix the Apple warning about the deprecated UIWebView:

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: did u figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of Android Studio running, it might be worth checking the logcat panel.